# Search for Shopware6 product variant

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is it possible in Shopware 6.x (via code or config) to allow users to search for a term, and have a product variant show up in the search result?

As of now, only the parent product is displayed, even if a search term has been added to a variant's Search keywords.

I've added search terms to a product variant, and run the indexer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the storefront presentation of the product.

- Edit the product in the administration.
- Select the tab "Variants".
- Click "Storefront presentation".
- Select "Product listings" in the sidebar menu.
- Select the "Expand property values in product listings" radio option.
- Select all property groups you want to be split in the storefront. If you select all every single variant will be listed separately.

This setting will adhere in both the search results as well as regular product listing. There currently is no way to set the storefront representation for just the search results but not the listing and vice versa.

Comment: Works as expected!  Thank you!